# How do I make Wildfly 10 / Resteasy indicate a serialization exception to the client

Tags: jakarta-ee, resteasy, undertow, wildfly-10

When an exception occurs during json serialization of a jax-rs response in Wildfly 10 the response is committed and the HTTP return code cannot be changed anymore. An exception of this is logged on the server side:

```
10:19:56,148 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-21) UT005023: Exception handling request to /ca00cefe-efd8-496c-a874-de0af20cad42/rest/: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: RESTEASY003770: Response is committed, can't handle exception
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also the json serializer nicely closes all open tags, so for the client the response is http code 200 with valid json. No indication of a failure whatsoever, only missing data.

How can I convince Wildfly / Resteasy / Undertow stop giving completely valid responses to the client when an exception occurs. Either a 500 response or not closing the json would be fine.

During my testing I found that when the exception is thrown no data has actually been send to the client, a Content-Length header is still added to the response. This might leave an opportunity to change the response code, however I was unable to find where this happens or why the reponse is marked as committed when nothing has been send yet.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/10
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 10
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 09:37:19 GMT

{"a":"ok"}
```

### Test case

**TestActivator.java**

```
package test;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class TestActivator extends Application {
}
```

**TestResource.java**

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Path("/")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public TestObject test() {
        return new TestObject();
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public class TestObject implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public TestObject() {
        }

        public String getA() {
            return "ok";
        }

        public String getB() {
            throw new RuntimeException("error");
        }
    }
}
```

**TestCase.java**

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.extension.rest.client.ArquillianResteasyResource;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class TestCase {

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
                .addPackage(TestResource.class.getPackage());
    }

    /**
     * This test should fail, either the response should not be 200 or a json exception should occur
     */
    @Test
    public void test(@ArquillianResteasyResource WebTarget webTarget) {
        Response response = webTarget.path("/").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(response.readEntity(String.class)));
        assertEquals("ok", object.get("a"));
        assertTrue(object.isNull("b"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out a way to achieve this.

Disabling AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET will result in a http 500 error on failure in most cases. Only exception I found is when a response exceeds a certain size, in that case something will start flushing the output. For that situation disabling AUTO_CLOSE_JSON_CONTENT will make sure the json document is not correctly closed on error.

```
package test;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Provider
public class MyObjectContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MyObjectContextResolver() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        objectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false);
        objectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_JSON_CONTENT, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> arg0) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered returning a `Response` object? This will have the both the status and your result. The client will check the status before retrieving the result, if the status is good:

```
/**
 * Creates a new contact from the values provided and will return a JAX-RS response with either 200 ok, or 400 (BAD REQUEST)
 * in case of errors.
 */
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createContact(Contact contact) {

    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = null;
    Long nextId = contactsRepository.keySet().size() + 1L;
    try {
        // Store the contact
        contact.setId(nextId);
        contactsRepository.put(nextId, contact);

        // Create an "ok" response with the persisted contact
        builder = Response.ok(contact);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle generic exceptions
        builder = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e.getMessage());
    }

    return builder.build();
}
```

A client would use it like so:

```
    // 1 - drop all contacts
    log.info("dropping all contacts");
    Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(REST_TARGET_URL).request().delete();
    Assert.assertEquals("All contacts should be dropped", Response.ok().build().getStatus(), response.getStatus());

    // 2 - Create a new contact
    log.info("creating a new contact");
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.setName(CONTACT_NAME);
    c.setPhoneNumber(CONTACT_PHONE);
    Contact persistedContact = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(REST_TARGET_URL).request().post(Entity.entity(c, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Contact.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("A book should be persisted with Id=1!", (Long) 1L, (Long) persistedContact.getId());
```

This is from a WildFly quickstart archetype:

[jaxrs-client: JAX-RS Client API example](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/10.x/jaxrs-client)

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same result, tested with "return Response.ok(new TestObject()).build();" in TestResource.test()